# How to upload/add array of classes?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to upload/add a new object precreated by one of my classes and I cannot do it because Angular tells me that I cannot use custom objects.

This is the code:

```
this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection<Lesson>('lessons');
this.itemsCollection.add(this.lesson);
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR Error: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Lesson object.
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I found out that using this.itemsCollection.add(Object.assign({}, this.lesson)); worked, but that does not suit me...

Comment: Hi @malrok44, the only solution I found is make a function to transform the class to a interface. It's a little bit weird, but when you've the function ready in the server, everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll dig into that.